# WEB MIDI + CSS Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, midi, web-midi

I'm trying to connect a MIDI controller to directly control CSS variables through the 'font-variation-settings' css property.

The MIDI control data comes as a UInt8 array such as [176,0,127] where the second value is the Control ID and the third value is the Control Value.

The CSS for the element looks like:

font-variation-settings: 'ABC' 99, 'DEF 400;

I've worked out a basic implementation where I can update ABC using the code below.

messageData.data is the UInt8 array

```
if (messageData.data[1] == 0) {
    var abc = messageData.data[2];  
}

var settings = "font-variation-settings: 'ABC' " + abc + ";" ;

text.setAttribute("style", ('font-variation-settings', settings));
```

The problem is that if I extend it to have two variables such as in the below code. When I move the second MIDI control (controlling DEF) it overwrites the ABC value, when I want to apply them together.

```
if (messageData.data[1] == 0) {
        var abc = messageData.data[2];  
} else (messageData.data[1] == 1) {
        var def = messageData.data[2];  
}

var settings = "font-variation-settings: 'ABC' " + abc + ', DEF' " + def + ";" ;

text.setAttribute("style", ('font-variation-settings', settings));
```

Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Comment: You messed up the quotes in the value you are assigning to `settings` in the second code snippet.

Comment: You only have the vars set within the "if - else" this means when you write this out then abc or def will say undefined.